# C++11: Does std::initializer_list store anonymous array? Is it mutable?

Tags: arrays, c++11, mutable, initializer-list, anonymous

Does the C++ standard say that `std::initializer_list<T>` is a reference to a local anonymous array? If it says, then we should never return such an object. Any section in the standard say so?

Another question, are the underlying objects of a `std::initializer_list<T>` mutable? I tried to modify it:

```
#include <initializer_list>
int main()
{
    auto a1={1,2,3};
    auto a2=a1;//copy or reference?
    for(auto& e:a1)
        ++e;//error
    for(auto& e:a2)
        cout<<e;
    return 0;
}
```

But compiled with error : error: increment of read-only reference 'e'

How can I fix it if I wish to change the value inside the initializer_list?

Comment: `initializer_list` is immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [dcl.init.list]:

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation
>   allocated a temporary array of `N` elements of type `const E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the
>   initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer
>   list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array.

That should answer both of your questions: copying the `initializer_list` doesn't copy the underlying elements, and the underlying elements are `const` so you cannot modify them.

> How can I fix it if I wish to change the value inside the `initializer_list`?

Don't use an `initializer_list<int>`. Use an `array<int, 3>` or `vector<int>` or some other container.

Answer (score 1):

From the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) article

```
Copying a std::initializer_list does not copy the underlying objects.
```